# ¿Como traducir una fecha al español?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

Tengo el siguiente código en codeigniter 4:

```
$recordset=$this->db->select('turno_id, paciente,date_format(fecha, "%W %d-%M-%Y %H:%i") as fecha,observaciones,obra_social,usuario_id' , false)
                                        ->where('year(fecha)','year(now())', false)
                                        ->where('usuario_id',$usuario_id)
                                        ->get("turnos");
```

Eso me devuelve la fecha de esta forma: `Wednesday 22-June-2022 23:16` y por medio de Datatables lo vuelco en una tabla.
¿Cómo hago para que me devuelva en español o traducirlo en español?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo solucioné. Como estoy usando codeigniter3 creé un modelo con el siguiente código:

```
$this->db->query("SET lc_time_names = 'es_ES'");
```

y luego lo cargué en config->autoload así

```
$autoload['model'] = array('Traducciondefecha_model');
```

El siguiente [artículo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17426887/codeigniter-timezone-mysql-settings) me dio una idea.

Answer (score 2):

¿Has probado usar `setlocale`? Yo lo utilicé en un código puro de PHP sin DB. Recibía la fecha de un campo y en un inicio imprimía de la misma manera que te imprime a ti. Pero con `setlocale` y una sintaxis un poco diferente, logré que imprimiera en español.

Te dejo el código a ver si te puede ayudar o darte una idea:

```php
<?php
//recibir los datos del formulario
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'spanish');
$fecha = $_POST["fecha"];
$fechaNueva = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($fecha));
$fecha=strftime("%A %d de %B del %Y", strtotime($fecha));  //fecha tipo martes 17 de mayo del 2022 
echo "$fechaNueva => la Fecha ingresada fue: ".$fecha
```

Comment: Gracias, Tu comentario me dio una guía.

Comment: Me alegro! Suerte!